# android webview p tag to have 100% width

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have a webview which has a p tag inside and the webview itself is has 90% of the device width by default, but I want that p tag to have a 100% width to fill the whole webview. I tried giving it via style:

```
<p style="width:100%"></p>
```

but this throws UnknowFormatConversionException. Here is my code to fill the webview with content:

```
    String head = "<head><style>@font-face {font-family: 'byekan';src: url('fonts/BYekan.ttf');}body {font-family: 'Tahoma';}</style></head>";
    String text = "<html>" + head + "<body style=\"background:#e4322f;min-height:" + minHeight + "\"><p style=\"width:100%;background:blue;direction:" + dir + ";font-family:byekan;color:#fff;text-align:justify;float:" + flt + "\"> %s </p></body></Html>";
    wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/",String.format(text, _content), "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

it works fine if I remove that "width:100%", but the p tag will takes the text width but I want it to fill the webview width, how can I achieve that? thanks in advance.